# 90s PC game: point and click diagonal layout

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember playing a game where I believe you play as a troll. (I might be wrong about the troll, I just remember the playable character was ugly looking.) Potions were involved. I remember specifically that the layout of the rooms were 3rd person diagonal layout.

I played it in the mid to late 90s. I wish I could remember if it ran on Windows 95 or 98. It was fully colored.

I know it’s a long stretch but if anyone remembers this, it’s one of the last things from my childhood that’s been haunting me.

Comment: “3rd person diagonal layout” — isometric?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Possibly worth posting some examples to give them an idea what you mean

Comment: Do you remember what part of the 90s you played this in, and which PC platform this was on?

Comment: I’d say mid to late 90s. And windows 95 I believe was the platform. Wish I could give more information, but I turned 10 in ‘98 so my memory is fuzzy. Thanks for any help

Comment: @Valorum Isometric as in, say, the game Fairlight. There's an in-game screenshot at https://spectrumcomputing.co.uk/index.php?cat=96&id=0001712 .

Comment: Speaking of Fairlight... According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairlight_(video_game)) there are trolls and potions involved. But it doesn't sound like you play as a troll.

Comment: Close, but the one in my head was later. I wish I could remember if it ran on 95 or 98. It was fully colored. I might be wrong about the troll, I just remember the playable character was ugly looking. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [*Planescape Torment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planescape:_Torment)?  The Nameless One is somewhat trollish looking, and it was isometric with a point-and-click interface.

Comment: Or Baldur's Gate...or Diablo?